# This context-free grammar is ambiguous and I'm not sure why. The SLR(1) compiler I'm building doesn't work the way I expect it to

Tags: parsing, syntax, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I'm building a syntax parser. It's going good to be SLR(1) but I believe there are some reduce/shift conflicts or some kind of conflict that is making the parser reject strings too early . Here is the grammar: 
Note: I did left factor the grammar to see if that was the problem, but that doesn't get rid of ambiguity. However this is the original grammar without left factoring

```
P'' -> P'$

P' -> P

P -> C | C;D

D -> R | RD

R -> pu{P}

C -> I | I;C

I -> h | O | A | R | Z 

O -> i(V) | z(V) 

Y -> u

V -> S | N 

S -> u

N -> u

A -> S=s | S=S | N=X 

X -> N | b | L

L -> d(X,X) | s(X,X) | m(X,X) 

R -> f(B)t{C} |  f(B)t{C}1{C}

B -> e(V,V) | (N<N) | (N>N) | nB | a(B,B) | o(B,B)

Z -> w(B){C} | r(N=0;N<N;N=a(N,1)){C}
```

I understand this grammar is quite big, but if you could help me here you would be a life saver. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, I think there are a few more transformations worth citing in the question that are not in the _relevant grammar productions_  ones, just like the `C -> I` one

Comment: I can't see, with the productions you gave, any way to produce a semi colon at the end of the string

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado I added the rest of the grammar

Answer (score 1):

Having recognized an `I`, and with `;` as the next symbol, there's a shift-reduce conflict:

- The production `C -> I;C` says to shift the `;`.
- The production `P -> C;D` says to reduce via `C -> I`.

So the grammar is not SLR(1).